# Send JSON to Flask using requests

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I am trying to send some JSON data to a Flask app using the requests library.  I expect to get `application/json` back from the server.  This works fine when I use Postman, but when I use requests I get `application/html` back instead.

```
import requests
server_ip = 'server_ip:port/events'
headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
event_data = {'data_1': 75, 'data_2': -1, 'data_3': 47, 'data_4': 'SBY'}
server_return = requests.post(server_ip, headers=headers, data=event_data)
print server_return.headers
{'date': 'Fri, 05 Jun 2015 17:57:43 GMT', 'content-length': '192', 'content-type': 'text/html', 'server': 'Werkzeug/0.10.4 Python/2.7.3'}
```

Why isn't Flask seeing the JSON data and responding correctly?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You are not sending JSON data currently.  You need to set the `json` argument, not `data`.  It's unnecessary to set `content-type` yourself in this case.

```
r = requests.post(url, json=event_data)
```

The `text/html` header you are seeing is the *response's* content type.  Flask seems to be sending some HTML back to you, which seems normal.  If you expect `application/json` back, perhaps this is an error page being returned since you weren't sending the JSON data correctly.

You can read json data in Flask by using `request.json`.

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/events', methods=['POST'])
def events():
    event_data = request.json
```

Answer (score 3):

If you use the `data` argument instead of the `json` argument, Requests will not know to encode the data as `application/json`. You can use `json.dumps` to do that.

```
import json

server_return = requests.post(
    server_ip,
    headers=headers,
    data=json.dumps(event_data)
)
```